# Xcode - Can't click inset tab bar item above tab bar

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a tab bar item that's inset to sit overlapping the top of the tab bar. The item is clickable within the tab bar, but not in the part of the circle image that's above the tab bar.

Is there a way to extend the tab bar item class to change the hit box, or increase the hitbox on the tab bar itself? I tried increasing the height of the tab bar, but I don't want the other items to move around.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. First use need to SubClass UIView.
2. Set that subclassed view to the view which is below the button.
3. Override hitTest in SubView like this,

   ```
   override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

       guard isUserInteractionEnabled else { return nil }

       guard !isHidden else { return nil }

       guard alpha >= 0.01 else { return nil }

       guard self.point(inside: point, with: event) else { return nil }

       if yourButton.point(inside: convert(point, to: yourButton), with: event) {
           return yourButton
       }

       return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
   }
   ```

   For more info you can refer this [blog](http://khanlou.com/2018/09/hacking-hit-tests/).

Comment: Sub class what UIView? this is for a tab bar controller with an item that has the button inset adjusted??